# SQL QUERY not giving required result when documents =0

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have one record with no documents (i.e., `Documents= 0`).  When I am executing the following query, it returns zero rows, but it should return my one row since I have one record with no documents.

How can I modify this so it will return the record with no documents?

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( Order By ParentID  ) AS RowNumber_ps,

UPPER(HostApplicationLocalData.ParentID) asParentID,

COUNT(Document.ID) as Documents from HostApplicationLocalData

inner join Document onHostApplicationLocalData.ID=Document.HostApplicationLocalData_ID

WHERE HostApplicationLocalData.TransactionType_ID = 1

AND Document.Removed=0

AND HostApplicationLocalData.Company_ID = 9000

AND ( SharePointURI is not null or ((SharePointURI isnull and Content_ID is not null )

or ((HostApplicationLocalData_ID is not null andHostApplicationLocalData_ID != 0 and Content_ID isnull))))

group by HostApplicationLocalData.ParentID )q

where Documents > 0

And

Documents = '0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking over your code, it seems most likely that the `INNER JOIN` (along with the filter `Document.Removed=0`) is excluding any record without an entry in the `Document` table, which would naturally mean that no values would show up with a `COUNT(Document.ID` = 0.

Try this version of the query, which converts the `JOIN` type to a `LEFT OUTER`, and adds a condition allowing the `Document.Removed` filter to pass through records where the `Document` record would return `NULL`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER( Order By ParentID  ) AS RowNumber_ps,
        UPPER(HostApplicationLocalData.ParentID) asParentID,
        COUNT(Document.ID) as Documents 
    FROM
        HostApplicationLocalData
         LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        Document ON
            HostApplicationLocalData.ID=Document.HostApplicationLocalData_ID
    WHERE 
            HostApplicationLocalData.TransactionType_ID = 1
        AND (Document.Removed=0 OR Document.HostApplicationLocalData_ID IS NULL)
        AND HostApplicationLocalData.Company_ID = 9000
        AND 
            (SharePointURI is not null or 
              ((SharePointURI isnull and Content_ID is not null ) or 
                ((HostApplicationLocalData_ID is not null andHostApplicationLocalData_ID != 0 and Content_ID isnull))
              )
            )
    GROUP BY HostApplicationLocalData.ParentID 
  )q
WHERE Documents = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But i tried it too.. With just a single condition. But what i want as a result is the no. Of records having no documents added to it. How can i get it? I tried using Documents < 0,  also the condition Documents <=0 and removed the condition documents > 0 but still it is not returning me the correct no. Of records.

Comment: Check the edit - after a closer review, you are likely filtering out the records you are looking for with your `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Alright thanks it was a great help. If it will work.  I will let u know and approve ur answer.

Comment: Hey.  I tried using left outer join but did not acquire the result..  Can u give me any more help?

Comment: Can any one help me out of this?